# Java compile time unreachable code error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting compile time "unreachable code" error on below line in my program:

System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0, j = 5;
    tp: for (;;) 
    {
        i++;
        for (;;) 
        {
            if (i > --j) {
                break tp;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j);
    }
}
```

kindly help me out to find the exact cause for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's analyze this code:

```
tp: for (;;)  //<-- similar to while(true)
    {
        i++; //increases i by 1
        for (;;)  //<-- similar to while(true)
        {
            if (i > --j) { //decreases j and compares its value against i
                break tp; //breaks tp, which means breaking the outer for loop
            }
        }
        //while(true) above
        //if break gets executed, it breaks this for loop
        //so this line can never be executed
        System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j);
    }
```

Easiest solution:

Move  `System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j);` outside the outer `for` loop.

```
tp: for (;;)
{
    i++;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (i > --j) {
            break tp;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j);
```

Comment: @Diego No, because the outer loop can be exited if `i > --j` becomes true.

Comment: @Diego it is not. Since `break tp;` get's executed, the outer `for` loop stops, so the next statement after it, which is `System.out.println(...);`, gets executed with no problems.

Comment: oh I see, I thought it would restart the outer for. I guess I have to review how that labels work on Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `System.out.println` code can't be reached ever, even if `i` is greater than `j`.  The only `break` sends you `breaking` out of the outer `for` loop.  The `System.out.println` statement is after the inner `for` loop, but in the inner `for` loop, you either keep looping, decrementing `j`, or you `break` the outer `loop`.  There is no way to reach the `println` statement.

To print what `i` and `j` are after the loop ends, move the `System.out.println` call after the ending brace of the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The *inner* loop is an infinite loop. The only way to exit it is when `i > --j` is true, but this will break the *outer* loop (due to the call of `break tp;`) and the program will immediately execute the next code after the *outer* loop. That means there is no condition where the *inner* loop terminates "normally" so the next code after it can run.